# Backbone destroy entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm creating a app that allows users to add movie titles to their homepage. This is (finally) working pretty well. I'm using the backbone on rails gem.

I'm using the following code to create a new entry in my collection

```
events: -> 
  "click li": "addEntry" 

addEntry: (e) -> 
  movie_title = $(e.target).text()
  @collection.create title: movie_title
```

This is my collection

```
class Movieseat.Collections.Movieseats extends Backbone.Collection

  url: '/api/movies'
  defaults: 
    title: ""
```

But I was wondering how would I destroy a entry? When I look up destroy on the Backbone page it says `Destroys the model on the server`. But I don't want to remove the whole model, just a entry in the model.

I would make a new event like this, but obviously this wouldn't work.

```
events: -> 
  "click .destroy": "destroyEntry" 

destroyEntry: (e) -> 
  @collection.destroy $(e.target)
```

After some googling I found that it should be remove instead of destroy, but this code doesn't work. While it does work in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8chHf/)

```
destroyEntry: (e) -> 
  thisid = @$(e.currentTarget)
  thisitem = @collection.get(thisid)
  @collection.remove thisitem
```

Comment: `But I don't want to remove the whole model, just a entry in the model.` What's your collection? Is it a global list common for all users. And are movie titles movies selected by each user?

Comment: Every user adds a movie to his profile. So I would have to remove a movie record from the user model?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Backbone Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) - it makes scenarios like this waaaay easier to manage.

It comes with a built in Composite View which basically holds a collection and each model in the collection comes with an ItemView that holds the model.

Then you can listen to the events of the contents of that specific model view. So you have access to `@model.get('id')`. Which makes it really easy to do a `@collection.remove(@model.get('id'))`.

It also comes with a built in pub sub framework, so in your ItemView you could say

`@trigger "movie:title:removed", @model`

And in the parent Compositive view you can do a

```
@listenTo "childview:movie:title:removed", (movie) ->
  @collection.remove(movie)
```

Comment: I would rather learn the basis of Backbone before diving into Marionette, but I´ll keep this post in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is this code:

```
destroyEntry: (e) -> 
    thisid = @$(e.currentTarget)
    thisitem = @collection.get(thisid)
    @collection.remove thisitem
```

First off, you don't need to get the `Model` to remove it from the `Collection`; `remove` can also take an ID.  This isn't advertised very well in the Backbone docs, but if you look at the source you can see that `remove` does handle the `get` for you:

model = models[i] = this.get(models[i]);

So, you can simplify things to:

```
destroyEntry: (e) -> 
    thisid = @$(e.currentTarget)
    @collection.remove thisid
```

But that still doesn't solve things because your `thisid` isn't a string, it's a jQuery array.  Backkbone expects IDs to be:

> an arbitrary string (integer id or UUID)

So, it all boils down to your `@$(e.currentTarget)`, and how you stored your `Model`'s ID on it.  Did you use the `Model`'s ID as the element ID?  If so you can just do:

```
thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).attr('id')
```

If on the other hand you're storing the ID in data, you'd want something more like:

```
thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).data('id')
```

Ultimately the key thing is just that you need a valid ID in order for `remove` to work.  Once you get such an ID it should resolve your problems.

Comment: It seems I'm having some problems understanding the relations between Rails and Backbone. I'm not sure if I'm actually adding entries to the rails Movie model. I can't find any using my console.

Comment: You should consider the two to be almost entirely distinct, as Rails handles the server-side and Backbone handles the client-side.  The main points of interaction between the two are when you call `fetch` on a `Backbone.Model` (in which case Rails passes data to Backbone) and when you call `save` on a `Backbone.Model` (in which case Backbone passes data to Rails).  If you're not seeing data get created on the server you'll want to debug the `save` method of your `Model`.  You might also want to watch the `Net` tab of your developer console to see if an AJAX request is generated when you save.

Comment: When I save a movie it does do a AJAX request to save the data. The data also gets renderd instantly. When I check my /api/movies.json file I get a output like this, `{"id":1,"title":"Star Wars 1","created_at":"2014-10-18T21:15:56.737Z","updated_at":"2014-10-18T21:15:56.737Z","user_id":1},{"id":2,"title":"Star Wars 1","created_at":"2014-10-18T21:16:08.040Z","updated_at":"2014-10-18T21:16:08.040Z","user_id":1},` when I save another movie it gets added to the json file. So if I wanted to remove a movie, I would have to look for the ID of that movie.

Comment: I'm a little confused: are you storing your server-side data in a file or in a database?

Comment: Doesn't a JSON file get it's content from a database?

Comment: By definition a file is stored in the filesystem, while a database stores records.  You can certainly store JSON in a database record, but usually then you would have one record per JSON object (vs. the code in your comment above where you seem to have the JSON for two objects together).

Comment: After some much needed sleep I used DbScherma to get a visual of my  Sqlite database. Here I could see I have two tables. Users and Movies. When I add a Movie on my homepage it creates a new record in my Movie table containing a ID, Title and User_ID collumn. If I add the same movie as a different user I get another entry. So users don't share those records. Every User has a new record.

Comment: I think we've moved past the original question and in to the realm of server logic, which really deserves a separate SO question.  The short version though is if you want your server to re-use movies, you need to add logic to whatever part of your code does the saving to make it look for existing movies with the same name and then set the id of the new movie record to have the same ID as the existing movie record.

Comment: Thanks for your help! There were a few problems, first of all I had to use the Backbone destroy command instead of remove. And secondly I had to create a destroy method in my rails Movies controller. This topic might be of interest for others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449256/backbone-remove-row-by-id/26450103?noredirect=1#comment41541932_26450103.