# Backbone remove row by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to remove a row in a table with Backbone. I'm using Rails 4 and the backbone-on-rails gem for this project.

I'm using a addEntryevent to add row in my Movies table. This adds a new row containing a id, movie_title and user_id.

The index view

```
class Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/index'] 

  initialize: -> 
    @collection.on('update', @render, this)
    @collection.on('add', @appendEntry, this)

  render: -> 
    $(@el).html(@template())
    @collection.each(@appendEntry)
    this

  events: -> 
    "click li": "addEntry" 
    "click .remove": "removeEntry" 

  addEntry: (e) -> 
    movie_title = $(e.target).text()
    @collection.create title: movie_title

  removeEntry: (e) -> 
    thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).closest('div').data('id')
    console.log thisid
    @collection.remove thisid

  appendEntry: (entry) ->
    view = new Movieseat.Views.Entry(model: entry)
    $('#entries').append(view.render().el)
```

When I click on the .remove element I get a console log result showing the id stored in the element I want to remove.

The Entry view

```
class Movieseat.Views.Entry extends Backbone.View

    template: JST['movieseats/entry']
    className: 'movie-frame'

    render: -> 
      $(@el).html(@template(entry: @model))
      this
```

This is my index.jst.eco template

```
<h1>Movies</h1>

<div id="entries"></div>
```

This is the Entry template I render in the index.jst.eco template (i'm doing this so I only rerender the movie movies added to to the view.

```
<div class="movie-frame" data-id="<%= @entry.get('id') %>">
    <p><%= @entry.get('title') %></p>
    <p class="remove">Remove</p>
</div>
```

And my Backbone routes,

```
class Movieseat.Routers.Movieseats extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    '': 'index'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Movieseat.Collections.Movieseats()
    @collection.fetch()

  index: ->
    view = new Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

But there's no network activity when I click on the .remove element. There is network activity when the addEntry event is triggerd.

Comment: Try with removing the indentation, currently addEntry and removeEntry are methods of the events object. Define them as methods of the View itself.

Comment: The indentation was from pasting the code. In my editor the indentation is correct.

Comment: Fine. Well, currently the question seems to be unanswerable without having more context. Is `.movie-frame` child/descendant of the view?

Comment: @Vohuman I've updated my post with some more details. `.movie-frame` is (so far I can see) just a container renderd by the Entry view.

Comment: Could the problem be that in my Movie Rails Controller I haven't defined a destroy method?

Comment: Well, according to documentation `Collection.remove()` expects model objects, I don't think it will work by passing id to it, have you tried `@collection.get(thisid).destroy()`?

Comment: I just tried it and now I am getting a Delete request, `9
/api/movies/
DELETE 
404 Not Found
text/plain` But when I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/movies/9` I get a a page showing the movie title. Alright! Creating a destroy method in my Rails controller now removes the movie from the model!

Answer (score 1):

So apparently `@collection.remove` doesn't put out a HTTP request. Changing this to `@collection.get(thisid).destroy()` does the trick. But you will still need to create a destroy method in your Rails controller,

The removeEntry event in the Backbone view index,

```
removeEntry: (e) -> 
  thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).closest('div').data('id')
  @collection.get(thisid).destroy()
```

The destroy method in the Rails controller,

```
def destroy
  movie = Movie.find_by_id(params[:id])
  movie.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => {:msg => "item deleted!"},:status => 200}
  end

end
```

Comment: Actually `@collection.remove` can remove the models, but you should pass a Model to it not a model id.

Comment: When you say "pass a Model" you mean a Backbone model right. The way I see it is that a Model is the table I've generated with Rails `rails generate model Movie title:string` Could you explain the difference between a Rails Model and a Backbone Model?

Comment: Right, you can get the Backbone model from the collection and then pass it to the `remove` method, `collection.remove` exists so we can pass several models to it to be removed. Backbone models are just _representations_ of the server-side models, modifying them without syncing them with sever-side database effectively has no effect.